# Is there an algorithm for finding constants (A and B) of the sequence x = m*A + n*B?

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I have an array elements of which are the members of sequence **x[i] = m*A + n*B**, where A and B are some constants, m and n are integers **(range=(-1000,1000))**. How can I find the constants A and B with only having the array?

#the counter **i** is not depended from m or n

I thought about finding a multiple repeated difference between i and j elements of the sequence, but I don't know how exactly to do it.

P.S.
My knowledge of Linear Algebra prompts me that this might be an insoluble problem.

Comment: Are A, B, x real or integer ? For given x[i], are m and n completely unknown and unrelated ?

Comment: Can you give a small example of input and what output you'd like? At the moment it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Assuming that a solution is found, it might not be unique, because, say, mA+nB = (2m)(A/2)+3n(B/3) - assuming that 2m and 3n are still in the range.

Comment: A, B, x are real, and for x[i]   m and n are completely unrelated. 
(an example of the array i will comment later this day)

Comment: m, n can be different for each x[i]?